# PHPExcel Localizar celda por su título

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Buenos días,

Desde PHP estoy leyendo información de un documento Excel (.xls).
Sé que para leer el valor de la celda se hace:

```
$valor    = ($sheet->getCell("M".$fila)->getValue());
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿y si en lugar de leer el valor indicando la letra de la celda Excel necesito leer el valor en base al título que tiene asignado?

El documento Excel tiene una cabecera de la cual no me interesa extraer nada. Y en la fila 8 están los títulos asignados a cada columna, a partir de ahí ya vienen los datos.

Por favor, ¿podéis indicarme cómo puedo hacerlo? Estoy bloqueado.

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos,
Ricardo

Comment: Hola Ricardo. Aqui las preguntas se tiene que mostrar lo intentado. Lo que sea que probste y no funcionó. Explica mejor como tienes el archivo `.xls` y qué deseas hacer. Mira [ask] para más informacion. Un saludo

Comment: Ok, disculpa. Ya he conseguido lo que pretendía. Era tan sencillo como aplicar el método: $cell->getColumn con esto me devuelve "A, B, C...". Y $cell->getValue() para obtener la etiqueta del título que identifica a esa columna. Saludos.

Comment: puedes hacer una respuesta tu mismo siguiendo [answer] para futuros usuarios con un problema similar ^^